# What are the possible reason for swelling a coin battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

A CR2032 lithium battery is powering a Bluetooth LE based smart device. During the long-hours- continuous-testing, the battery in some test pieces got swollen. The heat is controlled max 80°C. Battery and PCB are mounted in a anti-vibration rubber based sealing material. The strange part is, this happens only to some test pieces. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: You can't expect things to fail at exactly the same time/point when used out of specification. If you could then that would guaranteed performance and would thus instead become be your specification.

Comment: 80C heat would probably do it.

Comment: @DKNguyen make sense. so i may imagine, some battery still works at the 80°C but some started making gas inside.

Answer (score 3):

Swollen batteries are a common cause of failures. It is the sign of gases being created inside the battery, usually because of excessive temperature or deep discharging that catalyse different reactions. 80°C is very hot for a battery, and "long hours continuous testing" hint at deep discharging as well = winning combination.

Comment: But there are many test samples, but swelling happens only to few samples only!

Answer (score 3):

> Any idea what could be the reason?

Have you read the data sheet of your specific battery? Here is one from a garden variety Energizer CR2032 and it's operating temperature is -30C to +60C
https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr2032.pdf

If your battery has similar specs, you are violating specifications and all bets are off. Use high temp rated battery instead.

Comment: But there are many test samples, but swelling happens only to few samples only!

Comment: If you are violating the specs, the behavior is undefined. If the batteries are spec'ed to be good up to 60C, this means that 100% of the batteries will be ok. If you are operating at a higher temperature, some may fail. How many is unknown. There is reason or incentive for the manufacturer to characterize or test past the stated limits